# Add configurable products to cart display waring message instead of redirecting

Tags: magento2, addtocart

In magento 2, by default, if I try to add configurable products to cart when not selecting any swatch values, I will be redirect to product page.

[image]

How can I prevent this and display a message like in product detail page instead of redirecting?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve an output similer to product detail page in product list page,

So copy **list.phtml** file from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` into your theme **if not exist**

so the new path will be something similer to  `app/design/frontend/[NAMESPACE]/[THEME]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

then in **list.phtml** file **find below code and replace**

```
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "product_sku": "<?= /* @NoEscape */ $_product->getSku() ?>"
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

with

```
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>   
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After replacing code, flush the cache (**`php bin/magento cache:flush`**) and see the store front, will get expected output.

**logic will work like product detail page** more reference find code in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

**Sample output for all the scenarioes with Magento LUMA product list page :**

[image: sample output]

Note : CSS work need. hope that can be done easily.

Comment: Thank you! I did it!

Comment: @HieuDuong,  you'r welcome, thanks for accepting answer, if you like my answer please do up vote also. :)

Comment: I did up vote but the number will not increase due to my reputaion.

Comment: @HieuDuong no issue :)

Comment: @Kanhaiyalal is that possible to show popup message instead of that required message?

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR Yes, this is possible but JS code change required, can be make all validation message to popup message for globally or page specific via JS override or via JS Mixin.

Comment: @Kanhaiyalal do you have any reference or source? you can also answer my question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298981/how-to-customise-validate-custom-js-so-it-will-return-message-in-popup