# Configurable product will not redirect to product view page after click on add to cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart, redirect, popup

if a customer forgets to choose the product option of the configurable product on the product listing page and click "add to cart" it is redirecting you to the product view page with the message: "You need to choose options for your item."

I just want to show this message in a popup without redirecting on the product view page.

I found out the controller and makes the change, but it's not working as per expectations.

File: Add.php

File Path:

> \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add

```
protected function goBack($backUrl = null, $product = null)
  {
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
  //  return parent::_goBack($backUrl);?>
               <script type="text/javascript">
                                       require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'], function ($, alert) {
                    function callpopup() {
                        alert({
                            title: $.mage.__('Some title'),
                            content: $.mage.__('Some content'),
                            actions: {
                                always: function () {
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        </script>
  <?php  }

    $result = [];

    if ($backUrl || $backUrl = $this->getBackUrl()) {
        $result['backUrl'] = $backUrl;
    } else {
        if ($product && !$product->getIsSalable()) {
            $result['product'] = [
                'statusText' => __('Out of stock')
            ];
        }
    }

    $this->getResponse()->representJson(
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($result)
    );
  }
```

1.it is still redirecting, even after I commented major line of the function.

2.it is throwing an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".

Any help, suggestions or advice for any other way to achieve this functionality will be appreciated.

Comment: Check answer here:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284396/add-configurable-products-to-cart-display-waring-message-instead-of-redirecting